# How to filter JSON and XML. PHP

Tags: xml, json, twitter

I have a function that gets friends and followers of a twitter account. I'm making a "Who's Not Following back app" How do I filter the xml/json data (I can use both) ie to echo what is in following but not in followers.

Here's my code

```
function twitter_notf_page($query) {
        $user = $query[1];
    if (!$user) {
        user_ensure_authenticated();
        $user = user_current_username();
    }
    $request = API_URL."statuses/friends/{$user}.xml";
    $tla = lists_paginatedd_process($request);
    $request = API_URL."statuses/followers/{$user}.xml";
    $tl = lists_paginatedd_process($request);
    $content = "<h2>FRIENDS</h2>";
    $content .= theme('notf', $tla);
    $content.="<br><hr>";
    $content .= "<h2>FOLLOWERS</h2>";
    $content .= theme('notf', $tl);
    theme('page', 'Followers', $content);
}

function lists_paginatedd_process($url) {
    // Adds cursor/pagination parameters to a query
    $cursor = $_GET['cursor'];
    if (!is_numeric($cursor)) {
        $cursor = -1;
    }
    $url .= '?cursor='.$cursor;
    $xml = twitter_process($url);
    $ret = simplexml_load_string($xml)

    return $ret;
}
```

Results - Following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users_list>
<users type="array">
<user>
  <id>66968592</id>
  <name>DJ Swaggz &#11013;click2fol</name>
  <screen_name>DjSwaggz</screen_name>
</user>
<user>
  <id>288859268</id>
  <name>tegan shanks</name>
  <screen_name>teganxroshanks</screen_name>
  </user></users_list>
```

Results - Followers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <users_list>
    <users type="array">
    <user>
      <id>66968592</id>
      <name>DJ Swaggz &#11013;click2fol</name>
      <screen_name>DjSwaggz</screen_name>
    </user>
      </user></users_list>
```

I want this guy to display (The one that's not following back)

```
 <user>
      <id>288859268</id>
      <name>tegan shanks</name>
      <screen_name>teganxroshanks</screen_name>
      </user>
```

Comment: can you post the returned xml as an example?

Comment: Okay, trying it out. Give me some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
<?PHP
function get_nonfollowers($followingXml, $followersXml)
{
    $following = simplexml_load_string($followingXml);
    $followers = simplexml_load_string($followersXml);

    $notFollowingMe = array();

    foreach($following->users->user as $f)
    {
        $isFollowingMe = false;
        foreach($followers->users->user as $follower)
        {
            if(strcmp($follower->id, $f->id) == 0)
            {
                $isFollowingMe = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!$isFollowingMe)
            $notFollowingMe[] = $f;
    }
    return $notFollowingMe;
}

$followingXml = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users_list>
    <users type="array">
        <user>
            <id>66968592</id>
            <name>DJ Swaggz &#11013;click2fol</name>
            <screen_name>DjSwaggz</screen_name>
        </user>
        <user>
            <id>288859268</id>
            <name>tegan shanks</name>
            <screen_name>teganxroshanks</screen_name>
        </user>
    </users>
</users_list>
EOF;

$followersXml = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users_list>
    <users type="array">
        <user>
            <id>66968592</id>
            <name>DJ Swaggz &#11013;click2fol</name>
            <screen_name>DjSwaggz</screen_name>
        </user>
    </users>
</users_list>
EOF;

$notFollowingMe = get_nonfollowers($followingXml, $followersXml);
print_r($notFollowingMe);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [id] => 288859268
        [name] => tegan shanks
        [screen_name] => teganxroshanks
    )
)
```

**Loop through the screen names**

```
foreach($notFollowingMe as $user)
{
    echo $user->screen_name . "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: No Problem :), btw there were errors in the sample XML you posted, the <users> tag did not have an ending tag, I'm assuming you wrote the example by hand and it wasn't the actual output from twitter? (just something to lookout for, if the output was from twitter).

Comment: Yeah I wrote that by hand, the fields were too much. I had to cut it short. Thanks. It works magic.

Comment: Hey, but how do I loop through the [screen_name] . I can't do it. Its been giving me stuff like 1 0

Comment: Loop through which screen names? The ones in the $notFollowingMe array? Edited my answer, check at the bottom of it.